# Does Linux 0.11 support swap space?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, paging

I'm currently looking into Linux 0.11 source code.
I can't find any swapping mechanism in the page_fault_handler or any other part of the code. It seems that 0.11 doesn't support swap space for main memory. Please tell me, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Seems like swap support was added in Linux 0.12 (January 15, 1992), [here's the commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/history/history.git/commit/?h=0.12&id=2ab763b2e26be65551e717bd547497ffb9ba7267) (`2ab763b2e26be65551e717bd547497ffb9ba7267`). The implementation is at [`mm/swap.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/history/history.git/tree/mm/swap.c?h=0.12&id=2ab763b2e26be65551e717bd547497ffb9ba7267) and the file did not exist prior to this point.

The relevant excerpt from the commit message is:

> Major milestone! Over the christmas break, I implemented paging to
> disk, meaning that you could actually use gcc on a 2MB system.  Some
> poor sod (Robert Blum) wanted to use Linux on such a system, and
> couldn't get the kernel to compile with anything less "bloated" than
> gcc.
>
> [...]
>
> **Virtual memory.**
>
> In addition to the "mkfs" program, there is now a "mkswap" program on
> the root disk.  The syntax is identical: "mkswap -c /dev/hdX nnn", and
> again: this writes over the partition, so be careful.  Swapping can
> then be enabled by changing the word at offset 506 in the bootimage to
> the desired device.  Use the same program as for setting the root file
> system (but change the 508 offset to 506 of course).
>
> NOTE! This has been tested by Robert Blum, who has a 2M machine, and
> it allows you to run gcc without much memory.  HOWEVER, I had to stop
> using it, as my diskspace was eaten up by the beta-gcc-2.0, so I'd
> like to hear that it still works: I've been totally unable to make a
> swap-partition for even rudimentary testing since about christmastime.
> Thus the new changes could possibly just have backfired on the VM, but
> I doubt it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's still too much for me to go through the kernel source code. Thank you very much for finding good information for me.